# PDDL: How to pass from 2D to 3D

Tags: 3d, pddl

I'm just started working with PDDL and I have developed a 2D project. Where can I find some online tutorial for a 3D PDDL?

I have tried to see online but there aren't so many helps on 3D PDDL. I didn't find any good code example also.

Comment: You should edit your question to add your model, otherwise it is unlikely you'll get any help.

Comment: Let me see if I can help. Are you talking about Planning Domain Definition Language or some other meaning of the acronym. If you are indeed talking about planning, what do you mean by 2D and 3D? If eukledian space dimensions, can you include a specific example?